# weka: automatically apply attribute selection

Tags: java, attributes, machine-learning, classification, weka

I am using weka on a huge dataset with many attributes.
So is there any possibility to apply the output of a feature selection automatically? Without having to delete hundreds of features by hand? (In the explorer)

If anyone knows, this would be a plus:
What would be the command for the CLI? (I often use scripts to process a lot of data / classifiers)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite possible from the Explorer and the CLI.

In the explorer on the Preprocess tab, there is a box labeled Filter.  If you select the Choose button, and expand some of the folders in the new window you will find both supervised and unsupervised attribute filters.  After selecting an appropriate filter your selection will appear in the Preprocess Filter box.  You can double click this box to expose a window with options that allow you to further define your filter.  This window will also contain buttons called More and Capabilities which will allow you to learn more about your selected filter.

For your task some good filters might be:

1. filters > supervised > attribute > AttributeSelction
   This is a way to apply some built in Weka attribute selection procedures.
2. filters > unsupervised > attribute > Remove
   This will allow you to provide the indices of the attributes you want to remove from your dataset.

To implement these attribute filters and others in the CLI I suggest looking at these two sources.  They do a better job explaining than I could ever hope to do.

- [Source one](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Performing+attribute+selection)
- [Source two](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Primer_)